# creating an array from a pd.date_range()

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, date, dtype

I got error while trying to get this array (passed days by beginning each month of the year)

```
array([  1,  32,  60,  91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335])
```

How can I get the desired array from  the code below or other code suggestions?

```
xticks = (pd.date_range('1/1/2015','31/12/2015', freq = 'M') - 1 + pd.Timedelta('1D')).strftime('%-j').astype(int)


TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a date range by specifying the frequency as `MS` (Month-Start)

```
pd.date_range('1/1/2015', '31/12/2015', freq='MS').dayofyear.to_numpy()
```

---

```
array([  1,  32,  60,  91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335],
      dtype=int32)
```